# Is there a way to change git's default configuration file?

Tags: git, configuration, configuration-files, git-config, xdgutils

I see `git` allows me to choose any file I want as a global exclude file but it can't see that you can change the default global configuration file ?

Did I miss it or is it impossible? Are there workarounds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git has 2 kinds of [global configuration files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-XDGCONFIGHOMEgitconfig). One is `~/.gitconfig` and the other is `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`.

When `~/.gitconfig` does not exist, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` works as the global configuration file.

We can create multiple `git/config` under different paths, for example `/e/git/config` and `/f/git/config`.

```
mkdir -p /e/git
touch /e/git/config
mkdir -p /f/git
touch /f/git/config
```

When we want to use one of them as the global configuration file, first we rename `~/.gitconfig`.

```
mv ~/.gitconfig ~/.gitconfig.bak
```

And then assign a path to `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` with either `export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=` or `XDG_CONFIG_HOME=`,

```
# use /e/git/config
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/e
git config --global user.name foo
git config --global user.email foo@xyz.com

# use /f/git/config
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/f git config --global user.name bar
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/f git config --global user.email bar@xyz.com
```

To use different names and emails,

```
git init test
cd test
touch a.txt
git add a.txt
# use foo and foo@xyz.com
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/e
git commit -m'hello foo'
# disable XDG_CONFIG_HOME
unset XDG_CONFIG_HOME

touch b.txt
git add b.txt
# use bar and bar@xyz.com
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/f git commit -m"hello bar"
```

When we want to use `~/.gitconfig` again,

```
mv ~/.gitconfig.bak ~/.gitconfig
```